# How was Klall Yisrael able to have the miracle of being gathered between the two poles of the Aaron HaKodesh if they weren't able to be near it?

Tags: miracle, joshua--book-of, ark-aron-kodesh

I recently saw while learning Navi that before crossing the Jordan that Yehoshua gathered all of Klall Yisroel and told them that they would experience miracles in their conquest of Eretz Yisroel. Rashi cites that he gathered them (Yes all 600,000 of them) between the 2 poles of the Aaron and the Malbim cites this that once they saw that it was understood that they should prepare for the what to behold the next day.

This may sound a little trivial, but if they were explicitly (see [Yehoshua 3:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.3.4?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))  commanded before not to approach the Aaron by 2000 Amos how could they have been gathered between the Aaron for the miracle to even occur?

Comment: Citing chapter and verse for your first paragraph would make it easier for others to look up and perhaps find you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the same way 600,000 could fit between the poles, an extra 2,000 *amoth* on all sides could fit in as well.